# DNS issue with Squid 3

Tags: domain-name-system, squid

I use a  Linux gateway (Ubutnu Server) to provide internet on my local network. I also use Opendns for website blocking. I have used Opendns servers on the gateway to forward DNS requests. However, for some users, there should not be website blocking. So, I have installed squid3 proxy, and have set it up with Google's DNS servers like so: `dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`. After I setup the client's browser to use squid proxy, certain websites (which I have blocked on Opendns) remain blocked. And, it seems like Squid forwards DNS requests to Opendns and not to Google's DNS servers because I get Opendns's site blocked page. So, how can I configure Squid to use Google's DNS servers and not the local DNS client for resolving DNS.

Comment: You restarted Squid after adding `dns_nameservers`?

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS requests are emitted from `squid3`. Then they have to go through your `OpenDNS` on your gateway.

This cascading of DNS requests redirection is a source of difficulties
you encounter.

I advise you to choose clearly `squid3` or `OpenDNS` to do what you want.

If you want to work at the DNS level, and this is what you want to filter,
stay with `OpenDNS`.

If on the other hand you want to work at the web level, and this is what you want to filter,
stay with `squid3`.